# Choosing the best fit from given plots

Tags: functions, fitting, data

I have some data:

```
x={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
y={3.05,21.05,69.05,162.05,315.05,543.05,861.05,1284.05,1827.05,2505.05}
```

That I plot with `ListPlot`. I have two functions that I would like to check which one of them best fits my data. The functions are:

```
f1[x_]:=0.5 x + (4/2) x^3
f2[x_]:=0.5 x + (5/2) x^3 + 80
```

and I plot them along with data points that I have I get a plot:
[image]

Function `f2` is plotted red, and function `f1` is plotted blue. Function `f2` is seems to be the best fit to data points, but is there a way in which I can in Mathematica check this, not by using something like `FindFit` or `NonlinearModelFit`, but instead calculating say distances between points and plots and see which function gets data points closer to it. Is this a correct way of thinking about fitting? Is there a code that allows checking how close are data points to some model function, or two of them or even more?

Comment: The answer will depend on the error bars. Are they the same for all data points? Or are they proportional to the values? Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way is to use [`RootMeanSquare`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootMeanSquare.html) on errors when `f1 /@ x` and `f2 /@ x` are used as predictions for `y`:

```
RootMeanSquare /@ {f1 /@ x - y, f2 /@ x - y}
```

> {222.43, 79.95}